# promoting harvest package using jhsdk.jar

Tags: harvest

i am trying to connect to All Fusion Harvest using Java using jhsdk.jar,

I can able to connect to login into harvest and browse packages. But when I try to promote the  package the next level using the below java code,

```
JCaMovePackage jPro = context.getMovePackage();
jPro.setToState("ACEDEV13.06.00.00", "Integration Test (AIT)");
jPro.execute();
```

I get exception.

E03090050: ERROR: Could not get Move Package Process from Context.
com.ca.harvest.jhsdk.hutils.JCaHarvestException: E03090050: ERROR: Could not get Move Package Process from Context.

Please help me with this, Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

I used promotePackage() method and the process name should be created in the Harvest SCM server. Same process name to be set using setProcessName("promotePackages"). It worked.